# tableView unable to display data parsed from the web in json format

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I created an api using kimono and here is my code.

```
#import "PlayerRankingsTableViewController.h"
#import "RankingsTableViewCell.h"

#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kPlayerRankingsURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/bg6tcuuq?apikey=xgp4nU6xA9UcBWSe0MIHcBVbAWz5v4wR"]


@interface PlayerRankingsTableViewController () {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *playerRankings;

@end

@implementation PlayerRankingsTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];


dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    kPlayerRankingsURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(initializePlayerRankingsArray:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be rexrcreated.
}

- (NSArray *)initializePlayerRankingsArray:(NSData *)responseData {
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSArray *myPlayerRankings = [[json objectForKey:@"results"]objectForKey:@"collection1"];
self.playerRankings = myPlayerRankings;
NSLog(@"%@", self.playerRankings);

return self.playerRankings;

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [self.playerRankings count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
RankingsTableViewCell *cell = (RankingsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (RankingsTableViewCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

NSDictionary *rankings = [self.playerRankings objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

NSString *rank = [rankings objectForKey:@"rank"];
NSString *name = [rankings objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *points = [rankings objectForKey:@"points"];


[cell.playerRank setText:rank];
cell.playerName.text = name;
cell.playerPoints.text = points;


return cell;
}

@end
```

I think there is nothing wrong with data parsing process, because the console displays my data parsed from the web correctly.
However, when I ran the app, I saw nothing but a empty table.
Again, I think this might be something simple and new to programming.

Thank you in advance, and sorry for being such a burden.

Comment: I am sure you have a cell with `reuseIdentifier:@"cell"` that contains three labels which you are using to set rank name and points. Also you can use `NSLog` at various positions to make sure that cell is not `nill` etc.

Comment: I'm sure it's just a placeholder but in case it's not you might want to not publish your API key to a public forum

Comment: @WarrenBurton https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/bg6tcuuq?apikey=xgp4nU6xA9UcBWSe0MIHcBVbAWz5v4wR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `initializePlayerRankingsArray:` you shouldn't be returning the array because nothing it there to receive it. You have already set `self.playerRankings`, so that is enough.

What is missing from this method is `[self.tableView reloadData];` (which should be the last line after `self.playerRankings` is set).

Comment: So i add reloadData in initializePlayerRankingsArray?

Comment: Yes, after you get your data you need to reload the table

Comment: I added that line and whne i ran the app i got "terminatng due to uncaughtexception" right after json was logged to the console.

Comment: @ShawnClarke, what did that error message say? Usually it gives the reason for the uncaught exception.

Comment: @rdelmar I set an exception breakpoint and what got is [UITableViewCell playerRank]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee79d69d70

Comment: @ShawnClarke Did you change the class of the cell in the storyboard to RankingsTableViewCell? The error indicated that you're getting a UITableViewCell, not a RankingsTableViewCell.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I did, i declared those IBOutlets in rankingsTableViewCell.h

Comment: @ShawnClarke, that's not what I asked. You need to select the cell in the storyboard, and change its class to RankingsTableViewCell. Did you do that?

Comment: Oh I just did and that solved the problem. Thank you! @rdelmar